# Bash passing information from script to script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arguments, cgi

I have a bash CGI logging connections to my server, I want to that when a new connection is requested/stablised/served this script passes an argument/variable to another script running in the background? is this possible? how can i do this?

I have tried environmental variables but this will only work in the same shell and I cannot be sure both will be running on the same shell. I've tried writing to a file but how could i know when the file has been edited thus allow the second script to execute the command.

I'm starting to get crazy, this must be possible I cannot believe to "programs" cannot share information... :O

maybe i'm taking the wrong approach, can someone please advise?

Thanks,
Marco P.

Comment: Is the background script just hanging around waiting for input from the CGI script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

named pipes might be one way, although it is blocking:

setup:

```
mkfifo /path/to/named/pipe
```

cgi script:

```
echo "some data" > /path/to/named/pipe   # blocks until other script consumes!
```

background script:

```
while :; do
    read data < /path/to/named/pipe      # blocks until cgi script produces!
    do_stuff_with "$data"
done
```

Comment: [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) is another possibility so that the background script can wake up and do stuff when a new file arrives in a watched directory.

Comment: Thanks for your comment as a matter of fact I just found out about the fifo's always saw them around never checked them out, :P ill give it a try, also about inotify find it very interesting the only problem I see is that i have to run it and it doesn't give me the information until I end the command is there i was using inotifywatch (I think). How could I use it to get the info in real time? while comman running? hmmm fifo's again right? :P thanks a lot !

Comment: Thanks a lot! this worked beautifully... each day I love bash more and more, why do people still try to use compilers! xP I guess we need the to have Linux in the first place xD